# TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, chai

I am trying to use `enzyme` to assert DOM nodes. My `Component` looks like

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TransactionListRow from './TransactionListRow';
import {Table, TableBody, TableHeader, TableHeaderColumn, TableRow} from 'material-ui/Table';

export default class TransactionList extends Component {
  render() {
    const { transactions } = this.props;

    return (
      <Table>
        <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false}>
          <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Amount</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Transaction</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Category</TableHeaderColumn>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody>
          {transactions.map(transaction =>
            <TransactionListRow key={transaction.id} transaction={transaction}/>
          )}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
};
```

My `test` looks like

```
import expect from 'expect';
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import TransactionList from '../TransactionList';
import {TableHeaderColumn} from 'material-ui/Table';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

describe("<TransactionList />", () => {
  const mountWithContext = (node) => mount(node, {
    context: {
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(),
    },
    childContextTypes: {
      muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }
  });


  it('renders five <TableHeaderColumn /> components', () => {
    const wrapper = mountWithContext(<TransactionList transactions={[]}/>)

    console.log(wrapper.html());
    // expect(wrapper.find('thead').length).toBe(1);
    expect(wrapper.contains(<TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>)).to.equal(true)
  });
});
```

When I run this, I get

```
  ● <TransactionList /> › renders five <TableHeaderColumn /> components

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/transactions/__tests__/TransactionList.test.js:24:250)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

As per `Enzyme` [docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/contains.html),

> .contains() expects a ReactElement, not a selector (like many other
>   methods). Make sure that when you are calling it you are calling it
>   with a ReactElement or a JSX expression.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I removed the `import expect from 'expect` and ran it as

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import TransactionList from '../TransactionList';
import TableHeaderColumn from 'material-ui/Table';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

describe("<TransactionList />", () => {
  const mountWithContext = (node) => mount(node, {
    context: {
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(),
    },
    childContextTypes: {
      muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }
  });


  it('renders five <TableHeaderColumn /> components', () => {
    const wrapper = mountWithContext(<TransactionList transactions={[]}/>)

    // console.log(wrapper.html());
    expect(wrapper.find('thead').length).toBe(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('td').length).toBe(0);

    // this is not working
    expect(wrapper.contains(<TableHeaderColumn/>)).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

It fails now with

```
 FAIL  src/components/transactions/__tests__/TransactionList.test.js
  ● <TransactionList /> › renders five <TableHeaderColumn /> components

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      true
    Received:
      false

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/transactions/__tests__/TransactionList.test.js:26:164)
```

and with

```
expect(wrapper.contains(<TableHeaderColumn/>)).to.equal(true);
```

I get

```
      Warning: Unknown props `onMouseEnter`, `onMouseLeave`, `onClick` on <th> tag. Remove these props from the element. 
 FAIL  src/components/transactions/__tests__/TransactionList.test.js
  ● <TransactionList /> › renders five <TableHeaderColumn /> components

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/transactions/__tests__/TransactionList.test.js:26:166)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

I still can not assert on `ReactElement`

Answer (score 75):

That's not an `Enzyme` problem.

`expect(...).to` is `undefined` because you have installed [**expect.js**](https://github.com/mjackson/expect#toequal) and you are using [**chai**](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal) syntax.

this

```
expect(wrapper.contains(<TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>)).to.equal(true)
```

should be

```
expect(wrapper.contains(<TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>)).toEqual(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, please see my update. I am still confused

Comment: Have you tried using  `expect(wrapper.find('TableHeaderColumn').length === 5).toEqual(true); ` / `expect(wrapper.find(TableHeaderColumn).length === 5).toEqual(true);` ?

Comment: Thanks @QoP your first two lines helped me immediately. I suspect this would happen a lot for someone like me who went from unit testing with expect, to using the helper libraries, chia etc, and not noticing the subtle nuances with syntax.

Comment: Here comes another tripped up chai user! thank you QoP!

Comment: Interestingly enough, the Enzyme [docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/contains.html) show the `to.equal()` syntax usage without any reference to Chai. 

Comment: yes in Enzyme docs they are using the `to.equal()`

Any comment for it

Comment: @doug-wilhelm, "The documentation and examples for enzyme use mocha and chai." https://airbnb.io/enzyme/